# help contour integral and residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

compute

$$J= \int_\infty^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3-8i}$$

simplify your answer until you get a purely imaginary number

When I initially started this question, I put $z^3$ and $8i$ into polar form and got $\theta$ = $\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}$ where $k = 0,1,2$ so 
$$ 2e^{i\pi\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2k}{3}\right)}$$

However I am unsure of how to use this within the residue theorem and to solve to get the answer.

Comment: Do you know [Jordan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Comment: vaguely but I didnt think it applied to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so our integrand is $$
  f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3 - i8}
$$
The first order of business is to find the *poles* of $f(z$). In this case, those are simply the zeros of the denominator, i.e. the solutions of $z^3 = i8$. If $z=re^{i\varphi}$, i.e. if $z$ is expressed in polar coordinates, we know that $z^n = r^ne^{i\varphi n}$, so what we have to do is solve $$
  r^3 = 8 \quad\text{ and }\quad 3\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2} \mod {2\pi}
$$ 
with the understanding that we only care for solutions $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$ since $\varphi$ is supposed to be an angle. That yields the three poles $$
  p_1 = 2e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}, p_2 = 2e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}, p_3 = 2e^{i\frac{9\pi}{6}} = -i2 \text{.}
$$
Two of these poles ($p_1,p_2$) lie in the upper half plane and one in the lower half plane ($p_3$).

We now pick our contour. We let $\gamma_N$ be the path that goes from $-N$ to $N$ along the real axis, and then back to $-N$ along a half circle in the lower half plane. Let $C_N$ be that circle. Obviously, as $N$ gets larger, the part of $\gamma_N$ along the real axis approximates the integral we actually want to compute better and better. But what about the circle? We need to show that the integral along that goes to zero as $N \to \infty$. We have that $$
  |f(z)| = \frac{1}{|z - i8|^3} \leq \frac{1}{|z|^3 - 8^3} \text{if $|z| > 8$} \text{.}
$$
From that, we get (using that the length of $C_N$ is $\pi N$, and that all $z$ along $C_N$ have absolute value $N$) $$
  \left|\int_{C_N} f(z) \,dz\right| < \frac{\pi N}{N^3 - 24} \to 0 \text{ as $N \to \infty$.}
$$

Our contour $\gamma_N$ (for large enough $N$) includes exactly one pole - $p_3$ - and so we can conclude that $$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \,dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \oint_{\gamma_N} f(z) \,dz = -i2\pi\textrm{Res }(f, p_3)
$$
where the minus sign accounts for the fact that our contour goes around $p_3$ clockwise, not counter-clockwise.

So all that remains is to compute the residue of $f(z)$ at $p_3$. For that, we have multiple options. One would be to do a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{z^3 - i8}$, which would yield the residues at all of the three poles at once. But we only need the residue at the pole $p_3$, so we can save ourselves some work. Since the pole of $f$ at $p_3$ has order one, we know that $$
  g(z) = (z - p_3)f(z)
$$
is holomorphic at $p_3$, and therefore has a taylor series expansion around $p_3$, say $g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k(x - p_3)^k$. It follows $f$ has the *laurent* series expansion $$
  f(z) = \sum_{k=-1}^\infty g_{k+1}(x - p_3)^k
$$
around $p_3$, and the *residue* of $f$ at $p_3$ is then $$
  \textrm{Res }(f, p_3) = g_0
$$
since $g_0$ is the coefficient of $(x - p_3)^{-1}$ in that laurent series expansion. So all we have to do is find the *first* coefficient of $g$'s taylor series expansion around $p_3$, which is simply $g_0 = g(p_3)$. But we must be carefully when *evaluating* $g$ there, because direct evaluation obviously yields the indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$. But we can use l'hospital's rule to find $$
  \textrm{Res }(f, p_3) = \lim_{z\to p_3}(z - p_3)f(z) = \lim_{z\to p_3}\frac{z - p_3}{z^3 - i8} = \lim_{z\to p_3} \frac{1}{3z^2} = \frac{1}{3(-2i)^2} = -\frac{1}{12} \text{.}
$$

So *finally* we found that $$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z^3 - i8} = i2\pi\frac{1}{12} = i\frac{\pi}{6} \text{.}
$$

---

The same way of computing the resiude always works *if* the pole has order $1$. In other words, if $$
  f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}
$$
where $h$ has a zero of degree $1$ at $p$ and $g(p) \neq 0$ then $$
  \textrm{Res }(f, p) = \lim_{z\to p} (z - p)f(z) = \lim_{z\to p} \frac{(z-p)g(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{g(z) + (z-p)g'(z)}{h'(z)} \text{.}
$$

Comment: No im not entirely sure I have been doing it right

Comment: @user107783 Well you didn't really show us what you did, so it's hard to say were you went wrong...

Comment: I used $2i\pi(Res(\frac{1}{z^3-8i},w0)+ Res(\frac{1}{z^£-8i},w1)$. I then put 1 into the polar form mentioned above to get $e^(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $e^(\frac{5\pi}{6})$ putting these into the residue theorem my answer was $$\frac{2i\pi}{3}(e^(\frac{-3i}{6} + e^(\frac{-5i}{6})$$ which cannot be simplified further

Comment: @user107783 Can you *please* fix your MathJax, and try to get your fomulas *syntactically* correct? The things you write a hardly legible to me! I assume you mean $i2\pi\left(\textrm{Res }(f,w_0) + \textrm{Res }(f,w_1)\right)$ where $w_0,w_1$ are the two poles in the upper half plane. That looks OK. However, there is no pole at $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. I think you mean $2e^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$.

Comment: @user107783 What's "putting these into the residue theorem" supposed to mean? *How* did you find the residues at $w_0,w_1$?

Comment: I used $$ I = 2i\pi[\frac{1}{3z^2} + \frac{1}{3z^2}]$$ I then used $z= e^\frac{i\pi}{2}, e^\frac{5i\pi}{6}$

Comment: @user107783 I told you before - $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is *not*, I repeat IS NOT, a pole of your integrand! Neither is $e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}$, by the way. My answer states all the three poles. $e^{i\frac{5\pi}{6}}$ has the correct *angle* but misses a factor of $2$ at the front, and $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is completely bogus.

Comment: @user107783 I've updated my answer to include a computation of the residue at $p_3$. The same method works for $p_1,p_2$. Though if you need the residue at two out of three poles, partial fraction decomposition might be faster...

Answer (score 0):

Define an appropiate contour, e.g. the upper half plane (consider it as a half circle), and compute the integral over it by the use of Cauchy's residue theorem. The integral over the circle arc vanishes (it is essentially $r^{-3}$ times the length $\pi r$ for radius $r$). So you need the residue(s) at the singularities.

Comment: When I used the residue theorem, my answer however didnt come out as I expected so i'm not entirely sure I am using residue theorem right in this instance. I am using the upper half plane

Comment: @user107783 It get's a bit simpler if you use the lower half plane, because then you only need to compute one residue, not two. And the pole there has a simpler form, too. See my answer for details.